# C code question: Conditional not working on flash value

Tags: c, embedded

I have what I am sure is a simple question for this group yet alludes me.  I have the following c code:

```
  static uint16_t delta;

  delta = (uint16_t)Flash_Read_NUM(ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_101);
  if (delta == FLASH_EMPTY)
  {
      delta = DEFAULT_DELTA;
      Flash_Write_NUM(ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_101, delta);
  }
```

FLASH_EMPTY is a #define 0xFFFFFFFF

When I put a breakpoint on the if I can clearly see that delta is 0xffffffff.  Can someone tell me how to get into the conditional statement?

Thank you

I have tried a ton of things including uint64_t delta; uint32_t delta, etc.

Strangely enough if Flash contains 0xffffffff and I change the conditional above to
if (delta == 0x0) I will enter the condition...

I don't understand??

Comment: What's the declaration of delta?

Comment: static uint16_t delta;

Comment: Please edit question with that data.  uint16_t max value is 0xFFFF < FLASH_EMPTY, right?

Comment: I've tried static uint64_t delta; and removing the typecast also to no avail....

Comment: Re "*I can clearly see that delta is 0xffffffff.*", That's not true. The valued assigned to `delta` is a `uint16_t`, which can't be that large.

Comment: I gave you two answers below.  What the return type of Flash_Read_NUM()?

Comment: You gave the declaration of `delta`, but what about `Flash_Read_NUM`?

Comment: Yes....seems like the issue is deeper....I copied a file from github application and am using their functions ....it looks like Flash_Read_NUM calls another function Bytes2float....this ultimately returns the following -nan(0x7fffff) which clearly isn't 0xffffffff....I think I will have to look deeper into this function

Comment: Seems like the simplest solution here works

delta =  * (uint32_t * )(ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_101);

Comment: Are you sure you read the flash correctly? You say the flash contains `0xFFFFFFFF`, from where do you know that? From inside the debugger? Or do you read it external? If you do it external, do you do a inversion somewhere (either in the external reader or in your code or both?).

Comment: Please give a bit more context: What controller do you use, what kind of flash memory, have you a debugger attached, what is the definition of `Flash_Read_NUM`, ....

Comment: Also in case `Flash_Read_NUM` doesn't involve a `volatile` qualified access, then the compiler can decide to do strange optimizations that break the program.

Comment: And well, the root problem seems to be your debugger. "When I put a breakpoint on the if I can clearly see that delta is 0xffffffff"  Why did it do that? This would suggest that the debugger is broken. Eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

Problem is here `static uint16_t delta;`

you are declaring delta as a uint16_t variable, which can only hold values between 0 and 65535. The value returned by Flash_Read_NUM() is a 32-bit value (0xFFFFFFFF), which cannot be stored in a uint16_t variable. When you assign this value to delta, it gets truncated to fit within the 16-bit range, resulting in a value of 0xFFFF.

To fix this, you should change the type of delta to a 32-bit unsigned integer (uint32_t).

Something like this `static uint32_t delta; delta = Flash_Read_NUM(ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_101);` should work

Answer (score 0):

Your constant FLASH_EMPTY is numerically larger than what can be stored in a `uint16_t delta`.  If you want to compare only the lower 16 bit either cast or mask the value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_101 101
#define DEFAULT_DELTA 42
#define FLASH_EMPTY 0xFFFFFFFF

uint32_t Flash_Read_NUM(uint32_t page) {
    return FLASH_EMPTY;
}

void Flash_Write_NUM(uint32_t page, uint32_t delta) {
    printf("write\n");
}

int main() {
    uint16_t delta = (uint16_t) Flash_Read_NUM(ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_101);
    if (delta == (uint16_t) FLASH_EMPTY) {
        delta = DEFAULT_DELTA;
        Flash_Write_NUM(ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_101, delta);
    }
}
```

and example output:

```
write
```

The other good option if `Flash_Read_NUM` returns that `uint32_t` is to remove the cast and just make it a `uint32_t delta`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_101 101
#define DEFAULT_DELTA 42
#define FLASH_EMPTY 0xFFFFFFFF

uint32_t Flash_Read_NUM(uint32_t page) {
    return FLASH_EMPTY;
}

void Flash_Write_NUM(uint32_t page, uint32_t delta) {
    printf("write\n");
}

int main() {
    uint32_t delta = Flash_Read_NUM(ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_101);
    if (delta == FLASH_EMPTY) {
        delta = DEFAULT_DELTA;
        Flash_Write_NUM(ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_101, delta);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since OP didn't explain the data model they're using, they may have a good reason to only check those 16 bits. If this were the case, the second option here might not be what they want.

Comment: @JohnLeuenhagen Thanks.  I will revise it if op gets back or delete it entirely as   ridgerunnersjw's comment suggest a lot of context is missing.